# How to print to stdout from system command in Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-mocha

I have the following `Rakefile`

```
desc "Runs tests"
namespace :test do
    task :api do
        `mocha`
    end
end
```

When I run the command `rake test:api`, I don't get the nice output of dots that I would if I just ran the command `mocha`.

How do I print the output of a command real-time in a rake task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just `put` the output:

```
puts `mocha`
```

The backticks ` are calling the command *mocha* and return the output of the command.

You may also use `%x{}`:

```
puts %x{mocha}
```

Or you use `system`:

```
system('mocha')
```

Or you store the output for later use in a variable:

```
output = `mocha`
puts output
```

Comment: puts `mocha` did the job. Thanks.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that
    `puts \`mocha\``
won't print in real time - it'll wait until the entire command is done, and then print the final result. Also, loss of color. For those, you should use `system('mocha')`

Comment: Thanks @CodyPoll, didn't know of the difference between the backticks and system call